# Unable to resolve error :`RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: undefined at new DateTimeFormat (native) at Date.toLocaleString (native)`

Tags: javascript

I am getting error

```
RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: undefined
    at new DateTimeFormat (native)
    at Date.toLocaleString (native)
```

My code is(Java Script) :

```
   const printedDate = new Date;
    const printedDateStringFormatted = printedDate.toLocaleString();
```

I am assuming that the browser doesn't get the time zone and throws and error. However, if I can put a `try-catch` & set it to **UTC** or something else when there is no time zone, that would eliminate this issue.
Found this solution https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/pull/1067/files but I don't exactly know how can I incorporate something similar in my piece of code. Can anyone please assist/guide me in putting the code pieces together.

Comment: When I run that code in Chrome 78 on Windows 10, it runs fine. Can you provide more context into where you are running into this problem?

Comment: it runs fine for me too. But there are some automation scripts that run and this is where the QA run into issues and get this error.

Comment: So there's no way I can test it , I just want to make sure that there is a `default-locale` to handle if there is none set. hope I am making sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  printedDate.toLocaleString('en-US');
```

or whatever local you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: It should work without a locale. From the linked page: "To use the browser's default locale, omit this argument or pass undefined."...

Comment: @HereticMonkey -- I understand.  I said try this.  If this works then the next step is to understand why the browser's default choice is not working.

Comment: Sounds like it would be better as a comment than an answer then...

Comment: @HereticMonkey -- possible, can't tell without some interaction from the OP.